# Does docky support gnome-do-like functionality?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-do, docky

I've been a big fan of gnome-do with the docky theme, but it seems quite clear that the app itself is dead. On the other hand, docky is looking really slick! Recently, my gnome-do config got messed up, and I've been debating making the switch to docky.

The only thing holding me back from switching to docky is, does docky support gnome-do's search functionality?

Simple question, hopefully with a simple answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it looks as though the only way to 'integrate' the two is to run them as separate applications. Gnome-do integration is [planned in a later release of docky](https://launchpad.net/docky/+milestone/3.0.0), and there are some instructions on [running the two in parallel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6017/how-to-get-docky-to-work-like-gnome-do), but otherwise, no such luck.